# RabbitMQ shovel messages does not move them

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-shovel

In the rabbitMq webinterface I have the shovel plugin.

Hovever, when I use it to shovel messages then the graph that shows message rates goes up and down as-if something happens, but the Queued messages stays the same.

When I, with the webinterface, looks at the target queue then I can also see that the "message rate" changes, but nothing goes into the queued messages.

I don't even know where to look for errors so any help is appreciated.

**Added:**

I don't know what to add about my setup, as you most likely can read then I am not that familiar with RabbitMQ.

I have a queue for dead messages. I.e. messages that has been the result of some kind of error. When my queue is named myqueue then this queue is named myqueue.dead. After fixing a bug I shovel all from the dead queue to the queue to be processed again.

In the web-interface is the button for "Move messages". It normally works but now it doesn't.

Now I don't see messages gets moved, but if I quickly again click the dead queue then Even though the graph for queued messages are unchanged then the "Message Rates" chart quickly spikes with "Consumer ack" e.g.a red graph.

The same is visible in the target. It spikes with a lot of "Deliver manual" i.e. a blue graph. But it just goes up and down very fast and nothing happens.

Comment: So, I have no idea how to help because it's difficult to understand what you are trying to do and what you have going on. Can you provide some concrete details as to your setup and what you are seeing?

Comment: Thank you @theMayer. I decided to do it by Adding the explanation to the question and having the question itself remain unchanged.

Comment: Can you provide details as to your configuration... what would be necessary is a minimal setup to replicate the issue. Describe your setup in complete enough detail that I could replicate it on my system (it is not necessary nor desired to put domain-specific elements or names).

Comment: @ThomasKoelle did you ever find a solution? Sounds like the messages are send to the dead-letters-queue again.